# SQL - table schema change in trigger then update dependencies (views)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-view

Here is the scenario (code is C#):

We allow for the creation of columns on our tables from within our app. When a record is put into a table (our metadata table, going forward called mdt), we create a column on a table that corresponds to the data we just created in mdt. We have a trigger on mdt that does the creation of this column. At the end of this trigger we are updating all the dependencies for the table that just got the newly created column.

In SSMS I can run all the SQL and it works, however in code, all the SQL runs, but the dependencies are not updated. The code runs all SQL in a transaction, however I have run tests in SSMS using transaction and still, the SQL in SSMS works while the code in our app does not. By not work, I mean that the dependencies do not refresh. The column creation works which means that the trigger is firing in both cases which means that the code to try to regenerate the view dependencies is running.

So, in short:

Insert record > Fire trigger > Create Column > Refresh View Dependencies

SSMS - everything works

From code - everything works, except that the refreshing of the view dependencies is not actually refreshing the views

My first thought is that there is a difference in the way the transactions are being done (between code and SSMS), however I added code in the app that ran the script to refresh the view dependencies outside of the transaction that would end up creating the new column and still, the dependencies are not updated, however if I run the same SQL in SSMS, the dependencies are updated fine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

This is the code we are using to refresh the views:

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspRefreshViewDependencies]') AND type in ('P'))
DROP Procedure [dbo].[uspRefreshViewDependencies]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspRefreshViewDependencies](
    @nvcViewName nvarchar(776),
    @bitIncludeCustomerObjects bit = 1
)
AS

/*
This procedure will correct View and UDF dependencies after columns have changed.  Given the name of a View
for @nvcViewName, it will detect all of the Views and UDFs (both table-type and inline-table) that reference
them, and call sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule to update them.  It runs recursively (so it can correct dependencies
on dependencies on dependencies, and so on.)

if @bitIncludeCustomerObjects is false, the algorithm will skip custom database objects (anything in the dbo
schema that starts with the letter "c".)

This was created for managing Entity Views but it should also work for tables and UDFs.
*/

DECLARE c CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR


WITH dependencies (referencing_id, referencing_object_name, type, level)
AS
(
    SELECT referencing_id, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id), SO.type, 1 as level
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@nvcViewName)) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@nvcViewName)), 'OBJECT') sre
        INNER JOIN sys.objects SO ON sre.referencing_id = SO.object_id
    WHERE SO.type IN ('V', 'TF', 'IF', 'P')
        AND (
            @bitIncludeCustomerObjects = 1
            OR OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) NOT LIKE 'c%')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SED.referencing_id, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(SED.referencing_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(SED.referencing_id), SO.type, level + 1
    FROM dependencies D
        INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies SED ON D.referencing_id = sed.referenced_id
        INNER JOIN sys.objects SO ON SED.referencing_id = SO.object_id
    WHERE SO.type IN ('V', 'TF', 'IF', 'P')
        AND (
            @bitIncludeCustomerObjects = 1
            OR OBJECT_NAME(SED.referencing_id) NOT LIKE 'c%')
)

SELECT referencing_object_name, type, Max(level) as level
FROM dependencies
Where (OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id) <> 'Custom')
Group By referencing_object_name, type
ORDER BY level


DECLARE @nvcDependency nvarchar(776)
DECLARE @nvcType nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @intLevel Int

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @nvcDependency, @nvcType, @intLevel

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Refreshing ' + @nvcDependency
    EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule @nvcDependency
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @nvcDependency, @nvcType, @intLevel
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
Go
```

I have found out that when running this in SSMS that everything runs as expected, however when run from C#, that the CTE seems to not return any results and never gets into the cursor.

Comment: As posted there isn't a lot of detail here for somebody to offer much help. Not exactly sure what you mean by view dependencies. I think you mean the view is not getting refreshed? Some code would go a long way in explaining. I would however suggest that if you are adding columns from your application your design is going to be a nightmare. This is the type of situation where using a EAV (entity attribute value) data model is better suited. I am guessing that all your queries have to use select * because you don't know what columns might exist.

Comment: Added the stored proc we are using to refresh the views and the views' dependencies. Also found out that in code that the CTE in the store proc doesn't return anything, while in SSMS it does. Going to look into why that might be (and ultimately, that would be the issue).

Comment: Turns out, sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities is returning nothing when run from the app (but not from SSMS). This is probably a permission issue. I can use sys.sql_expression_dependencies instead.